# Remove a line from file if it exists

Tags: php, file, io

I'm getting used to PHP and trying to remove a line from a file (if it exists) and resave the file.

So if I had the file

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

I could use

```
if(existsAndRemove("user3")){
    do thing
}
```

I've tried using code similar to the code below but it sometimes bugs out and will only remove a line if it is last in the file. I have no idea how to fix this.

```
$data2 = file("./ats.txt");
 $out2 = array();
 foreach($data2 as $line2) {
     if(trim($line2) != $acc) {
         $out2[] = $line2;
     }
 }
 $fp2 = fopen("./ats.txt", "w+");
 flock($fp2, LOCK_EX);
 foreach($out2 as $line2) {
     fwrite($fp2, $line2);
 }
 flock($fp2, LOCK_UN);
 fclose($fp2);  
  }
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, and i would also appreciate if you could explain the code too so I could easier learn from it!!
Thank you.

Comment: Overwrite the opened file or save as new?

Comment: it just looks like you have not defined `$acc` ie `$acc = "user3";`

Comment: @Arbels Overwriting the file, sorry.

Comment: @cmorrissey it's already defined above I just failed to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file size is small enough that you're not worried about reading it all into memory, you could do something more functional

```
// Read entire file in as array of strings
$data = file("./ats.txt");

// Some text we want to remove
$acc = 'user3';

// Filter out any lines that match $acc, 
// ignoring any leading or trailing whitespace
//
$filtered_data = array_filter(
    $data, 
    function ($line) use ($acc) {
        return trim($line) !== $acc;
    }
)

// If something changed, write the file back out
if ($filtered_data !== $data) {
    file_put_contents('./ats.txt', implode('', $filtered_data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
function remove_user($user) {
    $file_path = "foo.txt"
    $users = preg_split("[\n\r]+", file_get_contents($file_path));
    foreach ($users as $i => $existing) {
        if ($user == $existing) {
            $users = array_splice($users, $i, 1);
            file_put_contents($file_path, implode("\n", $users));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be much easier since you're already using `file()`:

```
$data2 = file("./ats.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
unset($data2[array_search('user3', $data2)]);
file_put_contents("./ats.txt", implode("\n", $data2));
```

Or to check if it exists first:

```
$data2 = file("./ats.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

if( ($key = array_search('user3', $data2)) !== false ) {
    unset($data2[$key]);
    file_put_contents("./ats.txt", implode("\n", $data2));
}
```